# div having different appearances in different themes

Tags: themes, shortcode, css

I have a shortcode in a plugin that is supposed to display a div. The div can be styled in the settings.

The problem is: the div has different appearance in different themes. This obvious is caused by other themes modifying the styles in a generic way that I am not specifically handling.

What is the *optimal* solution such that its appearance remains same through out themes. One obvious one is to override **ALL** possible css properties in the my div related styles. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Have you considered using a `<section>`? Most themes do not style that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be specific when defining your CSS styles so that a theme will not overwrite your intended style.

When outputting your markup, perhaps you should even consider wrapping your div element within another div element and assuming this is the only markup on the page, you can specify them both with an #ID selector as opposed to a class selector, then in your CSS styling:

```css
div#myPlugin div#innerWrap {
    background: black
    /* etc */
}
```

...and so on.

That is going to be pretty hard to overwrite as you are being far more specific than what a theme could possibly ever be without the theme knowing the exact div ID names ahead of time, ***which they wont***.

You could also inject your styles inline which will take top precedence over all other defined styles,

```html
<div id="myPlugin">
    <div id="innerWrap" style="background:black">
         content
    </div>
</div>
```

**Inline wins!**

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no other solution. If you don't specify css property and theme specifies it, then the div will look according to theme specification.

You don't have to specify ALL CSS properties, but you definitely should specify common ones.